# API specific page in Azure API Management Developer portal

Tags: azure-api-management

I'd like to have a page or a section of information that only is relevant to a specific API. Is that possible in the new portal?

In this case it has to do with information about event data that is sent out (to webhooks) when new items are created and that are then available in operations for the API. If it's not possible to have i an "API-specific" page, where would you put something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe in this case you are trying to add some sort of static page or documentation to explain the functionality about a specific API. You may refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/78931/index.html). As mentioned in the thread, you can try with swagger but in APIM portal it might not work immediately. Microsoft product team has confirmed that they working on improving support for OpenAPIv3. The ETA is about end of September.

However, you may also check the [self-hosted gateway feature](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/selfhosted-gateway-feature-in-api-management-is-now-generally-available/)

> The self-hosted gateway feature expands API Management support for hybrid and multi-cloud environments and enables organizations to efficiently and securely manage APIs hosted on-premises and across clouds from a single API Management service in Azure.
> [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/self-hosted-gateway-overview)